# Force quit when using cursor adapter and custom list view (please help)

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter

I followed this example to try : [Link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html) . Then I cannot get the list view successfully.
The code is followings. Please help ,thank you.

```
package com.example.trydb3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int i = 0;
    private DBHelper dbhelper ;
    private ListView listView1;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);        
        displayListView();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void displayListView() {     
        Cursor cursor = dbhelper.fetchAllDatas();
        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                DBHelper.NAME, 
                DBHelper.TEL, 
                DBHelper.EMAIL      
        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] { 
        R.id.textView1, 
        R.id.textView2, 
        R.id.textView3
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.list_info, 
        cursor, 
        columns, 
        to,
        0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

}
```

dbhelper, I think the fetchAllDatas() has some problem but I dont know why as I can create and insert successfully.

```
package com.example.trydb3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends"; 
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String TEL = "tel";
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";  
    public final static String DATABASE_NAME = "demo.db"; 
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = 
                    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + TEL + " TEXT,"
                    + EMAIL + " TEXT" 
                    + ")";   

   public DBHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);       
  }
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {        
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        Log.d("Database operations","Database created successfully");       
    }   
    @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME; 
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);     
            onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
    public void insertData(String name, String tel, String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, name);
        cv.put(TEL, tel);
        cv.put(EMAIL, email);

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllDatas() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                NAME, 
                TEL, 
                EMAIL       
        };
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,  
        null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return mCursor;
        }

    public void insertSomeDatas() {

      insertData("PAUL","12345678","123@fjkds.com");
      insertData("JACK","987654321","345@fjkds.com");
      insertData("TOMMY","44444444","567@fjkds.com");

     }

}
```

And then it is the xml file for main and listview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.trydb3.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

log file:

```
    11-15 15:56:43.536: E/Trace(32348): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    11-15 15:56:44.186: D/AndroidRuntime(32348): Shutting down VM
    11-15 15:56:44.186: W/dalvikvm(32348): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trydb3/com.example.trydb3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at com.example.trydb3.DBHelper.fetchAllDatas(DBHelper.java:58)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at com.example.trydb3.MainActivity.displayListView(MainActivity.java:49)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at com.example.trydb3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    11-15 15:56:44.196: E/AndroidRuntime(32348):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DBHelper class you never assign anything to you `db` field.

One quick work-arround would probably be getting the db in your method:

```
public Cursor fetchAllDatas() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] columns = new String[] {
            NAME,
            TEL,
            EMAIL
    };

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}
```